# How to safely read a property from an unknown object?

Tags: typescript

I want to safely access a property of an `unknown` object (such as one produced by `JSON.parse`). First I check whether it's an object (or null) using `typeof x === 'object'`, and then I use optional chaining `?.[` to avoid reading a property of null.

This seems safe to me, however TypeScript still complains with:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"k"' can't be used to index type '{}'. Property 'k' does not exist on type '{}'.

```
function foo(x: unknown) {
    if (typeof x === 'object') {
        x?.['k'];
    }
}
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUAPAXI8BrMOAdzAEpEBvAKEVsRmETSgE8AHAUzkY0QF4BiAORwARgCsO0IeWp15iDAH4AdAG0heIQF0A3DToBfKoaA)

Is there a way to convince TypeScript I am accessing this property safely, preferably without downcasting/`as`?

Comment: It's not complaining that you're not accessing the property safely; it's warning that the type of the value returned is implicitly `any` and you likely have the `noImplicitAny` flag turned on. You have to tell it what type it should be, either be *explicitly* casting it as `any`, or casting it to a different type.

Comment: Hm. Good point, but adding `as unknown` at the end of the line doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Yeah, because the problem is with `x` not having a defined `k` property... This seems to work: `(x as {k:unknown})?.['k'];` but is kind of ugly. I'm holding out hope that one of the maintainers of TypeScript will show up -- they frequent Stack Overflow.

Comment: 1. `JSON.parse` returns `any`, not `unknown`. 2. IMHO the error is correct - x may indeed not have k. Type guard would help, but it incurs a runtime check 3. The same error appears on any other property access, if you use a key that does not belong to declared interface.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned JSON.parse as motivation but I know it actually returns `any`. However, I suspect if it were typed from scratch today it would be `unknown`, which is a relatively new feature. If I wrap it in some abstraction I prefer to treat it as `unknown`.